# Get plane from 3D polygon and normal

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I have a polygon defined by `n` points and a polygon `normal`.

- Now I want to get the plane of the polygon defined by

  - a plane `normal=(nx,ny,nz)`
  - and a constant `d` (distance from the origin to the plane).
- The plane normal is equal to the polygon normal, but how can I calculate d?
- desired plane equation `nx*x+ny*y+nz*z+d=0.0`

Answer (score 3):

Take any point *p*=(*p<sub>x</sub>*, *p<sub>y</sub>*, *p<sub>z</sub>*) on the plane and plug it into the equation to obtain *d*.

So if your equation is
*n<sub>x</sub>*·*x* + *n<sub>y</sub>*·*y* + *n<sub>z</sub>*·*z* + *d* = 0
then you get 
*d* = − (*n<sub>x</sub>*·*p<sub>x</sub>* + *n<sub>y</sub>*·*p<sub>y</sub>* + *n<sub>z</sub>*·*p<sub>z</sub>*).

Another common formulation is using *d* as the right hand side of the equation, in which case you get the reverse sign. I.e. for the equation
*n<sub>x</sub>*·*x* + *n<sub>y</sub>*·*y* + *n<sub>z</sub>*·*z* = *d* 
you get
*d* = *n<sub>x</sub>*·*p<sub>x</sub>* + *n<sub>y</sub>*·*p<sub>y</sub>* + *n<sub>z</sub>*·*p<sub>z</sub>*.